# Listview With Asynctask get no response from server

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

I want to send Cus_id from postParamName to web server. 
According to cus_id I want to fetch data from server and get it into listview.

I have no error in my code...but the code still not able to fetch data from server..

Plz look at my code...i have been working on this code since last two days. but I am not able to find the mistake

Point1.java

```
            public class Points1 extends ListActivity implements FetchDataListener {
SessionManager session;
TextView tvCusPoints1, tvCusPoints2, tvcusName;
TextView bus_name;
TextView cus_points;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.points);
    initView();
              }
            private void initView() {
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    // ID
    String cus_id = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParamName = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParamName.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cus_id", cus_id));

    String url = "http://10.0.2.2/android_api_main/business_points.php";
    FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
    task.execute(url);
}
      @Override
public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog

    // create new adapter
    ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(this, data);
    // set the adapter to list
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
      @Override
public void onFetchFailure(String msg) {
    // dismiss the progress dialog

}
        }
```

Application.java

```
      public class Application 
       {

   private String bus_name;
   private String cus_points;

public String getbus_name() {
    return bus_name;
}

public void setbus_name(String bus_name) {
    this.bus_name = bus_name;
}

public String getcus_points() {
    return cus_points;
}

public void setcus_points(String cus_points) {
    this.cus_points = cus_points;
}
    }
```

ApplicationAdapter.java

```
       public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Application> {
    private List<Application> items;

 public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, List<Application> items) {
    super(context, R.layout.point_list_item, items);
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.point_list_item, null);
    }
    Application app = items.get(position);
    if (app != null) {
        TextView titleText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_bname1);
        TextView dlText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_bpoint1);

        if (titleText != null)
            titleText.setText(app.getbus_name());
        if (dlText != null)
            dlText.setText(app.getcus_points());
    }

    return v;
}
       }
```

FetchDataTask.java

```
      public class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private final FetchDataListener listener;
private String msg;
String cus_id, responseString, success, bus_name, cus_points;
SessionManager session;

public FetchDataTask(FetchDataListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    if (params == null)
        return null;

    // get url from params
    String url = params[0];
    try {

        // create http connection
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        // connect
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
        // get response
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        // get response content and convert it to json string

    } catch (IOException e) {
        msg = "No Network Connection";
    }
    return responseString;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String sJson) {
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseString);
        JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("customer");
        List<Application> apps = new ArrayList<Application>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            bus_name = json_data.getString("bus_name");
            cus_points = json_data.getString("cus_points");
            success = json_data.getString("success");
            Application app = new Application();
            app.setbus_name(json.getString("bus_name"));
            app.setcus_points(json.getString("cus_points"));
            // add the app to apps
            apps.add(app);
        }
        if (listener != null)
            listener.onFetchComplete(apps);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        msg = "Invalid response";
        if (listener != null)
            listener.onFetchFailure(msg);
        return;
    }
}
              }
```

FetchDataListener.java

```
     public interface FetchDataListener {
public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data);

public void onFetchFailure(String msg);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your FetchDataTask constructor accepts FetchDataTaskListener as parameter

```
public FetchDataTask(FetchDataListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

But you have initialized it using activity's context

```
FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
```

Could you please check this.

You should set listener correctly, something like this

```
this.mListener = (FetchDataListener) activity
```